# cancancan authorization without params[:id] set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, cancan, cancancan

I'm trying to authorize "Locations". In the url, the param is not the Location id, but another field called "url_alias". So when searching for the right Location in the LocationsController, I don't use params[:id].

```
@location = Location.find_by(url_alias: params[:url_alias])
```

The route is looking like this:

```
resources :locations, param: :url_alias
```

In the ability.rb model, I use the following line;

```
can :read, Location, url_alias: "TestURL"
```

Now the problem is that CanCanCan doesn't use the information that I try to authorize by the url_alias field, I can view every Location I want. When I replace "url_alias" by a random value like "qwert", I don't even get an error that the field doesn't exist.

By setting params[:id] in the controller to a random value, everything works as expected again, cancancan authorizes by the url_alias etc.
I think it's not a really clean solution to work around this problem by just setting params[:id] to a random value in order to get CanCanCan working. So does anybody have an idea for a better solution? Thanks in advance!